# Kusto - Compare 2 query results and get the diff

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I would like to compare the HTTP 5xx and 2xx codes from the W3CIISLog in Azure Monitor using Kusto.

How do you return two or more values and then compare against eachother?

For example, I can return all 2xx and 5xx values using:

search "W3CIISLog"//
| where scStatus startswith "2" or scStatus startswith "5"

But then I want what each returns into a variable so I can then compare to eachother.

Thanks

Comment: Are you basically just looking for a right join? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer

Answer (score 1):

you can use `!in()` or an anti-`join`

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/inoperator
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator

for example:

```
let colors = datatable(c:string)
[
  'Red',
  'Green',
  'Blue',
  'Black',
  'White'
]
;
colors
| where c !in ((
  customEvents
  | ...
  | distinct Colours
))
```